# Disable Scrolling on mobile while drawing on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, mobile, scroll

I'm making a site, where you can draw on a HTML5 canvas, with the mouse or on mobile with touch.

But on mobile you scroll the site while you are drawing. Thats make the drawing very uncomfortable.I've tried that, but it doesn't work:

```
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
  var mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY
  });
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
  if (e.target.tag == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {});
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
  if (e.target.tag == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY
  });
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
  if (e.target.tag == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
```

Do you have any idea, how I can avoid scrolling on mobile, when you draw on canvas?

Thank you!

Comment: I am having the same issue, only mine is using phonegap to make mobile app and not on a website. Is this browser specific or cross browser for you?